# Write comments in Django

Tags: django, django-comments

These days I started working with Django, it's great!

I wonder if there is a "standard" to write comments in Django, for example, like codeigniter: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#commenting...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a good idea to follow the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) recommendations for commenting your code. Also see [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for additional information about docstrings.

Answer (score 0):

For Django views or any python file you can use the python style commenting

Like for single line comment your can try with

#

and for multiple line comment you can use  `""" """`

and in templates you can do the html style commenting

like `<!--   -->`

Comment: may be my answer is not much sophisticated but it will give you the basic idea